# Finding the joint density of two random variables

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose (X,Y) is uniformly distributed over the region { (x, y) : 0 < x < y < 1 }. Find the joint density of (X, Y). 
 I started out by drawing the unit square and filling in the area where 0 < x < y < 1, but from this point on I am unsure of how to proceed. Thoughts?

Comment: your start is okay. What is the surface of the area that you filled? The density on this is a constant $c$ and is zero elsewhere. What can be concluded about $c$?

Comment: The area of the triangle I shaded is 1/2. How do I find the density from this area?

Comment: For every density you must have $\int\int f\left(x,y\right)dxdy=1$. So find out what is on left side in your situation and substitute. It will lead you to the value of $c$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting confused. f(x) = c, according to what you said. How do I find the limits of integration? And where does the area of the triangle, 1/2 factor into this integration formula?

Comment: See my answer then. Note that $1/2$ is the area of the mentioned triangle.

Answer (score 0):

We have as density $f$ the function $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto c$
if $0<x<y<1$ and $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto0$ otherwise.

Then $1=\int\int f\left(x,y\right)dxdy$
leads to $1=c\times\int\int_{A}dxdy=c\times\frac{1}{2}$ so $c=2$.

Here $A=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\mid0<x<y<1\right\} $